# Memory usage on Teradata SLES linux server

Tags: linux, database, memory, memory-management, teradata

First of all i am new to Teradata.

My question is related to the 'normal' memory consumption on a small Teradata server such as mine. 
The sever in question is a 2 node machine(TD v.14.10) with 48 amps, 2 Parsing Engines and 96gb of RAM.

I run the `top` command from the command line and i notice that i have only about 600MB left of RAM memory. 
Most of the memory is allocated to processes with the name pdevproc and actmain(i believe this are AMP processes).
Each instance of these processes is allocated 2.9GB of RAM.

Is that normal and if not what should be done to lower the memory allocated?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for memory usage is something the Teradata generally manages very well without interaction on the part of the DBA. If you have questions about the utilization of memory on your system you should be looking at the ResUsageSpma table which will help explain how the database is utilizing memory in your environment.

If you have concerns about what is being reported at the OS level I would suggest contacting your Teradata CSR, your Teradata system engineer, or open an incident with the Teradata GSC. In my experience, I have never had to touch anything in the OS on a Teradata system with respect to system performance.

Your mileage may vary, but I hope this helps.

Comment: I run the following query `SELECT * FROM dbc.ResUsageSpma` in order to get the info you suggested but i get 0 rows. Is there a setting that i should change or something? I can't seem to find anything on the internet. Thanks for answering by the way

Comment: It sounds like ResUsage data collection has not been enabled. There should at least be data from the current day even if there is a historical data collection process moving the data to another database.